# Swift 2: "the error is not handled"

Tags: ios, swift2

Started to get

> "call can throw but it is not marked with try and the error is not
>   handled"

error after updated Xcode from 6.4 to 7 with swift2 in the `"contactUsObject.save()"`. How can I fix this?

```
@IBAction func postCommentBtn_clicked(sender: AnyObject) {


    if messageTxtComment.text.isEmpty  {

        let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Message field is empty", message: "Please enter a message to post", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: nil))
        self.presentViewController(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
    else {

        var theComment = messageTxtComment.text
        let len = messageTxtComment.text.utf16.count

        if len > 150 {

            theComment = theComment.substringToIndex(theComment.startIndex.advancedBy(150))

        }

        let contactUsObj = PFObject(className: "contactUsMessage")

        contactUsObj["username"] = PFUser.currentUser()!.username
        contactUsObj["email"] = PFUser.currentUser()!.valueForKey("email") as! String
        contactUsObj["name"] = nameField.text
        contactUsObj["enteredEmail"] = emailField.text
        contactUsObj["phoneNum"] = phoneField.text
        contactUsObj["message"] = theComment

        contactUsObj.save()


    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
do {
     try contactUsObj.save()
} catch error as NSError {
    print(error)
    //Handle any error.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to adopt to Swift 2.0 error handling using `do`...`try`...`catch` syntax.

Replace your:

```
contactUsObj.save()
```

Like:

```
do
{
   try contactUsObj.save()
}
catch _
{
    // Handle error here
}
```

Refer [Swift Error Handling](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html) for more information.